# Input from textboxes not displaying in a jQuery UI Dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, validation, textbox, jquery-ui-dialog

I am running into a problem where I want to display user input in a jQuery UI dialog box, but it isn't capturing any values. I know that the plugin works, but my code for displaying user input from textboxes in the dialog box seems to be shoddy. I commented out the code which breaks the plugin in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TR6gy/). I basically want whatever data the user puts in the textboxes to be displayed in empty divs that I created within the plugin confirmation window.

HTML:

```
First Name: <input type="text" id="name">
<br>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="last">
<br>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Activate Plugin">

<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation">Please confirm that the following information is correct: <br>
First Name: <div id="firstinput"></div>
Last Name: <div id="lastinput"></div>
</div>
```

Working jQuery plugin code with commented out non-working code:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#dialog').dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              width: 600,
              buttons: {
                  "Correct": function() {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  },
                  "Incorrect": function() {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
              }
          });

          $('#button').click(function() {
              $('#dialog').dialog('open');
              return false;
          });
      });
      /*INPUT FROM TEXTBOXES DISPLAYING IN THE PLUGIN CONFIRMATION WINDOW LOGIC
      $(document).ready(function () {
          if $("#first").val() {
              $(this).appendTo("#firstinput");
          }
          else if ("#last").val() {
              $(this).appendTo("#lastinput");
          };
      });*/
```

I would really appreciate it if someone took a look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TR6gy/) and gave me an idea of what I might be doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong for your `if` statement. There is no `#first` element. `$(this)` inside your if statement refers to the `document` element and so can't be appended to `#firstinput` or `#lastinput`

Comment: @RGraham is it possible for me to accomplish what I am trying to do with this method? How should my syntax look? Sorry, I'm pretty new to web development.

Comment: There is no real need to call dialog multiple times as you have. Check my answer below for a solution that uses much less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is actually built into the dialog method.

http://jsfiddle.net/TR6gy/2/ : Here is an example.

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        width: 600,
        open: function () {
            $('#firstinput').html('<span>' + $('#name').val() + '</span>');
            $('#lastinput').html('<span>' + $('#last').val() + '</span>');
        },
        buttons: {
            "Correct": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Incorrect": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The `open` event will allow you to trigger a custom function upon opening the dialog. This is much more efficient as you are are not adding multiple events or functions to your button.

More info here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: This seems like the best solution, so I'll choose it as the answer despite other peoples' fiddles working just fine. Thanks to everyone, upvotes ahoy. Also I was trying to read through API documentation yesterday but it just seemed too cryptic. At least I can understand what the working code does now.

Comment: When first starting out, it can be a little confusing. Once you get used to it though, documentation is your best friend. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have udpated the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w5Pa/)

Here are the changes what I did.

```
   <div id="dialog" title="Confirmation">Please confirm that the following information is correct: <br>
        First Name: <label id="firstinput"></label><br>
        Last Name: <label id="lastinput"></label>
    </div>

        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
              $("#firstinput").text($("#name").val());
              $("#lastinput").text($("#last").val());
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the necessary code inside your button click handler instead:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    if($("#name").val()) {
        $("#firstinput").text($("#name").val());
    }
    if($("#last").val()) {
        $("#lastinput").text($("#last").val());
    }
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

[<kbd>Updated Fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/SBR9f/)